# Can a configMap of type array be created in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Does the following configuration for configMap create the test.json file of type `empty array` or `string []`

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myconfigmap
data:
  test.json: |-
    []
```

The convertor to JSON suggests string:

```
{
    "kind": "ConfigMap",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "myconfigmap"
    },
    "data": {
        "test.json": "[]"
    }
}
```

My goal is to create configMap file with empty array.

Comment: What's your definition of a file with empty array? What does it contain? Is the file binary or text file? What's the representation of an empty array in a file?

Comment: Kubernetes syntax allow to create it, did you test it?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can make it whatever string you want, it just has to be a string. The thing you *can't* do is `test.json: []` since that's an array. The fact that your string happens to be valid JSON is not something K8s knows or cares about.

Comment: You mean the value for the key has to be a string, but it actually creates a file with empty array?

Comment: If you mean you are mounting this as a volume, the contents of the string are the contents of the file.

Comment: The bigger question is how is the OP's app handling an empty array file? A CSV could be an array file where each field is an array element. Therefore to have a 0 element CSV all he needs is an empty file.

Comment: It says `test.json` so I'm hoping it's a JSON formatted "file" :)

Comment: It's JSON, the app will treat this file as JSON with empty array to start with and update it using k8 API. Now if this indeed is an array, it can be updated using ```PATCH```. But if this is a string, then that's a problem.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. Will this `test.json` contain string that the app can parse and pull the empty array? Or will this file contain the elements of an array? If the latter, shouldn't a 0 byte file suffice? If the former, shouldn't a string `[]` suffice?